# Why I get an empty file when I try to sort it?

Tags: bash, sorting

I am trying to sort a file with following command : `sort ${filename} > ${filename}` , and I get as result - an empty file.
Can someone explain why I get this result and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is a inplace `sort` so which may not be supported, try instead.

```
sort ${filename} > temp_file && mv temp_file ${filename}
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, because Bash truncates the file before `sort` can read from it. Apart from @RavinderSingh13’s answer, which is the standard way to fix it, you could also use `sponge` from the `moreutils` package:

```
sort ${filename} | sponge ${filename}
```